# String matching in java

Tags: java, string, string-matching

I am currently struggling with my "dirty word" filter finding partial matches.

example: if I pass in these two params replaceWord("ass", "passing pass passed ass")

to this method

```
private static String replaceWord(String word, String input) {
    Pattern legacyPattern = Pattern.compile(word, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = legacyPattern.matcher(input);
    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
    int index = 0;
    while(matcher.find()) {
        returnString.append(input.substring(index,matcher.start()));
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
            returnString.append('*');
        }
        returnString.append(word.substring(word.length()-1));

        index = matcher.end();
    }
    if(index < input.length() - 1){
        returnString.append(input.substring(index));
    }
    return returnString.toString();
}
```

I get p**sing p**s p**sed **s

When I really just want "passing pass passed **s.
Does anyone know how to avoid this partial matching with this method??
Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: So you want some white space in front of `ass`?

Comment: You want to look at [Word Boundary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) should point you in the right direction.

You want to use a word boundary in your pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bword\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Note, however that this still is problematic (as profanity filtering always is). A "non-word character" that defines the boundary is anything not included in `[0-9A-Za-z_]`

So for example, `_ass` would not match.

You also have the problem of profanity derived terms ... where the term is prepended to say, "hole", "wipe", etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a dirty word filter as we speak, and the option I chose to go with was [Soundex](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Soundex.html) and some regex.

I first filter out strange character with \w which is [a-zA-Z_0-9].

Then use soundex(String) to make a string that you can check against the soundex string of the word you want to test.

```
 String soundExOfDirtyWord = Soundex.soundex(dirtyWord);
 String soundExOfTestWord = Soundex.soundex(testWord);
 if (soundExOfTestWord.equals(soundExOfDirtyWord)) {
     System.out.println("The test words sounds like " + dirtyWord);
 }
```

I just keep a list of dirty words in the program and have SoundEx run through them to check. The [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) is something worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `replaceAll()` method from the `Matcher` class. It replaces all the occurences of the pattern with your specified replacement word. Something like below.

```
    private static String replaceWord(String word, String input) {
        Pattern legacyPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = legacyPattern.matcher(input);
        String replacement = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
           replacement += "*";
        }
        replacement += word.charAt(word.length() - 1);
        return matcher.replaceAll(replacement);
    }
```